# IntelliJ Spring properties auto completion in *.yml files

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've been trying to make IntelliJ treat `*.yml` files the same way it treats `application.yml` or `bootstrap.yml`.

What I mean is, that I have auto completion and syntax warnings when I edit for example a `application.yml` file, but none of these features when I edit a file called `microservices-monitor-prod.yml` which is located in a config server resource folder.

Is there any way to have the same IntelliJ features when editing such files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 (currently available as RC) allows to choose custom naming schemes for Spring Boot configuration files (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133445)